# Changing background SVG url to the actual coordinates

Tags: svg

This is the whole code, what I'm trying to do is remove the background SVG url and replace it with the actual coordinates.

I thought by just replacing the url with the coordinates, it would look the same, but it doesn't.

How do I get the one using the coordinates to look like the one using the url? What has to be changed?

24 width
29 height

Exactly like this.

[image]

Above is 24 x 29.

This is 23 x 28

**-800 -700 2452 3399**

**Coordinates**

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1226 1481" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M0 1394V87C0 46.3 13.3 19.8 40 7.5 66.7-4.8 98.7.3 136 23l1034 634c37.3 22.7 56 50.3 56 83s-18.7 60.3-56 83L136 1458c-37.3 22.7-69.3 27.8-96 15.5-26.7-12.3-40-38.8-40-79.5z" fill="red"/></svg>
```

Coordinates with the rest of the code.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1226 1481" style="
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    left: 7px;
    top: 7px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 24px;
    background-position: 58% 50%;
    border-radius: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    cursor: pointer;
">

<path d="M0 1394V87C0 46.3 13.3 19.8 40 7.5 66.7-4.8 98.7.3 136 23l1034 634c37.3 22.7 56 50.3 56 83s-18.7 60.3-56 83L136 1458c-37.3 22.7-69.3 27.8-96 15.5-26.7-12.3-40-38.8-40-79.5z" fill="red"/>
 </svg>
```

This is what it looks like when I replace the url with the coordinates.

https://jsfiddle.net/9sok6ycs/2/

[image]

**Background-image url:**

https://jsfiddle.net/9sok6ycs/1/

This is what it looks like using the url.

I'm trying to get the above svg to look like this one.

[image]

```html
<div style="
        width: 64px;
        height: 64px;
        left: 7px;
        top: 7px;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTIyNiAxNDgxIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0wIDEzOTRWODdDMCA0Ni4zIDEzLjMgMTkuOCA0MCA3LjUgNjYuNy00LjggOTguNy4zIDEzNiAyM2wxMDM0IDYzNGMzNy4zIDIyLjcgNTYgNTAuMyA1NiA4M3MtMTguNyA2MC4zLTU2IDgzTDEzNiAxNDU4Yy0zNy4zIDIyLjctNjkuMyAyNy44LTk2IDE1LjUtMjYuNy0xMi4zLTQwLTM4LjgtNDAtNzkuNXoiIGZpbGw9IiNmZmYiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 24px;
        background-position: 58% 50%;
        border-radius: 500px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        cursor: pointer;
    "> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm offering you two very brief and relatively rough answers. You may just adjust  viewBox="..."  around your  icon or use transform matrix.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform

To reach a perfect result you may use something like SVGO for both of this variants. It provide you tuned SVG with removed transformations and accordingly recalculate coordinates at the paths and other elements.

```html
<svg viewBox="-800 -700 2452 2962" style="

    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    left: 7px;
    top: 7px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 24px;
    background-position: 58% 50%;
    border-radius: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    cursor: pointer;
">

<path d="M0 1394V87C0 46.3 13.3 19.8 40 7.5 66.7-4.8 98.7.3 136 23l1034 634c37.3 22.7 56 50.3 56 83s-18.7 60.3-56 83L136 1458c-37.3 22.7-69.3 27.8-96 15.5-26.7-12.3-40-38.8-40-79.5z" fill="red"/>
 </svg>
 </br>
 <svg viewBox="0 0 1226 1481" style="

    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    left: 7px;
    top: 7px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 24px;
    background-position: 58% 50%;
    border-radius: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    cursor: pointer;
">

<path transform="matrix(0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 350, 380)" d="M0 1394V87C0 46.3 13.3 19.8 40 7.5 66.7-4.8 98.7.3 136 23l1034 634c37.3 22.7 56 50.3 56 83s-18.7 60.3-56 83L136 1458c-37.3 22.7-69.3 27.8-96 15.5-26.7-12.3-40-38.8-40-79.5z" fill="red" />
 </svg>
```

Comment: This is the perfect pixel size for 23 x 28,  -800 -700 2452 3399 / I'm looking for, 24x 29.